# 400 bad request in ruby but not curl

Tags: ruby, curl, net-http, ruby-1.8.7

I'm trying to make a https post request in ruby and it works in curl, but I get a 400 bad request in ruby and I'm having trouble figuring out why.

Heres the ruby code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/https'
require 'uri'
require 'json'

uri = URI.parse("https://api.parse.com/1/push")
http =  Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.host)
req['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
req['X-Parse-Application-Id'] = "abc123"
req['X-Parse-REST-API-Key'] = "abc123"

req.body = {:data => {:alert => "sup"}, :channels => ["notifications"]}.to_json

resp = http.start{|http| http.request(req)}

puts resp.inspect
```

This gives me a `#<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 BAD_REQUEST readbody=true>` response.

But the curl equivalent works just fine:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: abc123" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: abc123" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
    "channels": [
      "notifications"
    ],
    "data": {
      "alert": "sup?"
    }
  }' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/push
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should specify full url:

```
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new("https://api.parse.com/1/push")
```

Answer (score 14):

For me the problem was not making the request over SSL. Once I set the following line everything worked:

```
http.use_ssl = true
```

This wasn't the OPs problem, but I'm posting anyway because the error message is the same and this thread is one of the top google hits for the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_job(job_name)

        puts "Posting job #{job_name} to get test update order service"

        get_job_xml ="<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ns=\"http://os.uk/Test/GetUpdateOrders/1.0\">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <ns:GetTestUpdateOrdersReq>
             <ContractGroup>abc</ContractGroup>
             <ProductID>myproduct</ProductID>
             <Reference>#{job_name}</Reference>
          </ns:GetTestUpdateOrdersReq>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>"

        @http = Net::HTTP.new(@server, @port)


        request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(('/XISOAPAdapter/MessageServlet?senderParty=&senderService=faceNamespace=http://myco.uk/Test/GetUpdateOrders/1.0'), initheader = {'Content-Type' => 'text/xml'})
        request.basic_auth(@username, @password)
        request.content_type='text/xml'
        request.body = get_job_xml
        response = @http.request(request)


      end
```

I have defined my method like this and its working.